# import music from my ipad

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, music

i just re-installed my mbp, and have deleted whole disk. i think my music is safe because i had sync it to my ipad.

but after installation done, i can't get my music from my ipad. in iTunes, when i try to click sync music, it showing me an alert that iTunes will remove all music from my ipad.

i know i can sync with auto download purchase items. but i got this music not from itunes stores. i got it by copied from my band studio, ( and some just copied from cd)

do you know how to get the music sync back to the mac without delete from ipad?

Answer (score 1):

The fantastic thing with iExplorer is that it not only transfers and imports your media data into iTunes but also imports the playlists. And you can access all data, even the preferences files from the apps. And you can make backups on your own on app basis if you like. :) Great software, fully worth the ~ 35 dollars.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes can't, but some third-party App let you transfer music from iOS device. 
For example, [iExplorer](http://www.ibrowseapp.com) 3 app specializes in this and makes iTunes media transfers incredibly quick and easy. It has an Auto Transfer feature which will rebuild your entire iTunes library from any iDevice in a single, one-click transfer and include your playlists, play counts, ratings, and other metadata. It can also transfer any of your photos, videos, podcasts, text messages, ringtones, books, notes, voicemails, contacts, calendars, voice memos, and more to a Mac or PC.

Comment: do you tried the iexplorer?  
because i try using filza, its a jailbroken app for help me get access to all directory in my ipad, and i find all my mp3 file name is encrypted. so i dont know the titlle of every mp3 file

Comment: the name you can see are all the name in iTunes library, it's quit different with the original, but all the ID3 and album cover are all fine

Answer (score 0):

I've used PhoneView a couple times and I love it. It would do this for you.

http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/